# 503 Unavailable Service on Form Submit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I created a project with PHP Laravel and Vue JS. and configured it with Amazon AWS's basic plan. In the beginning, it worked well without any issues. But now, when I try to add a new blog post or edit already existed blog post with heavy content, it is showing 503 Service Unavailable error. I developed the algorithm for the blog as shown below.

Tables:

> 1. blogs - This table is used to store lightweight data of the post like title, featured image, URL, etc.
> 2. posts - This table is used to store the actual content of the post. It contains three columns like blog id, content, order. Here I am
>      using text datatype for content which will accept nearly 70k characters.

Algorithm:
When I submit a blog post, first it will create a row in the blogs table with lightweight data. And after that, the actual post content will be split into an array with each item contains 65k characters. And every item will be stored in the posts table as a new row with the blog id created in the blogs table. At the time of retrieving the post, it will join the rows in the posts table and will display the actual post.

Note: The above process is working fine without any issues.

Problem:
The actual problem is suddenly it started to show 503 error when I try to add a new post or edit the existed post with images(produces heavy amount of characters), even the post is being created in blogs table and incomplete amount of characters are adding in the posts table, while adding the rest of the content its showing 503 error.

Note: Even it is working fine on my localhost and another Bluehost server.

I tried to reduce the content splitting with 25k characters, but the result is showing the same.

```php
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = 'post_' . time() . '.' .$extension;
            $path = public_path('uploads/posts/' . $fileNameToStore);
            if(!file_exists(public_path('uploads/posts/'))) {
                mkdir(public_path('uploads/posts/'), 0777);
            }
            Image::make($request->file('image')->getRealPath())->resize(900, NULL)->save($path);
        }else {
            $fileNameToStore = NULL;
        }

        if($request->hasFile('author_image')) {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('author_image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('author_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $authorImage = 'author_' . time() . '.' .$extension;
            $path = public_path('uploads/authors/' . $authorImage);
            if(!file_exists(public_path('uploads/authors/'))) {
                mkdir(public_path('uploads/authors/'), 0777);
            }
            Image::make($request->file('author_image')->getRealPath())->resize(50, 50)->save($path);
        }else {
            $authorImage = NULL;
        }

        $blog = Blog::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'image' => $fileNameToStore,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'meta_description' => $request->meta_description,
            'meta_keywords' => $request->meta_keywords,
            'url' => $request->url,
            'meta_title' => $request->meta_title,
            'author_name' => $request->author_name,
            'author_image' => $authorImage,
            'author_linkedin' => $request->author_linkedin,
            'popular' => $request->popular
        ]);

        $contents = str_split($request->post, 65000);
        $i = 1;
        foreach($contents as $key => $item)
        {
            Post::create([
                'post' => $blog->id,
                'content' => $item,
                'order' => $i
            ]);

            $i++;
        }
```

I expect the output to be redirect back to blogs page with success message "Post has been created successfully", but the actual result is

Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: see your application logs... and `Image::make` are you using [`intervention/image`](http://image.intervention.io/)? in my experience, they do take a considerable ram for large images (depend on the processing engine) which may cause the hosting to curb your process if its too large. do check the server spec on amazon and your bluehost.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the intervention/image to resize the featured image of the blog post which will store on the blog's table. It is working fine now and the data being stored on the blogs table. But the issue is occurring when the data is being pushed into posts table. The images which are added in post content will be stored as encoded string in database.

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? Or can you turn on PHP error reporting?

Comment: No I don't have access to the server logs and Laravel will record PHP errors into logs file, but in that file, there is no error regarding this showing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to increase values of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`.
Guide for AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/wordpress-themes-2mb/

I also recommend using transactions for your case. This will help to avoid partially created posts. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found the limit was set to the lease values, now I changed the config as per my localhost and restarted the server using "service httpd restart" command. But now also it is showing the same error. Is there anything that I need to change?